# How do I stop mongoid 5 spamming the log in rspec

Tags: mongoid

I've tried:

```
  Mongoid.logger = nil
  Mongo::Logger.logger = nil
```

With no luck, I still get tons of messages like:

```
D, [2015-10-19T17:45:40.385610 #23054] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding localhost:27017 to the cluster.
D, [2015-10-19T17:45:40.387634 #23054] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mauka_test.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"system.namespaces", "filter"=>{:name=>{"$not"=>/\.system\.|\$/}}}
D, [2015-10-19T17:45:40.388258 #23054] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mauka_test.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000532895s
D, [2015-10-19T17:45:40.388739 #23054] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mauka_test.delete | STARTED | {"delete"=>"mauka_metrics", "deletes"=>[{"q"=>{}, "limit"=>0}], "writeConcern"=>{"w"=>1}, "ordered"=>true}
D, [2015-10-19T17:45:40.389092 #23054] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mauka_test.delete | SUCCEEDED | 0.000283895s
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at [the mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/redline-gh/mongo_beautiful_logger/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spec/rails_helper.rb, you can increase the logger level for mongo like:

`Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::WARN`

Change WARN, to INFO or FATAL depending on what you want. DEBUG is the default.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I can swear I've tested this before maybe guard did not reload.